# Codewars exercise showing error for code that works fine on my system

Tags: ruby

Here is the problem

correct the code so that greet function returns the expected value
This is given code

```
class Person

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(other_name)
   "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{name}"
  end
end
```

and this is my solution

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name, :other_name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(other_name)
    puts " \"Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{@name}\" "
  end
end

object = Person.new("Joe")
object.greet("Kate")
```

It is giving following error

```
`expect': Expected: "Hi Kate, my name is Joe", instead got: nil (Test::Error) from `assert_equals' from `
'
```

Answer (score 2):

`puts` is a method that returns `nil`, so even though you see the correct output, the test doesn't see it that way.

Comment: This should be right, try replacing 'puts' with 'return'

Comment: @nextstep Or, just remove `puts`.

Comment: Thanks alot it works
In future in situations like this How should I find that where to use puts or print or return?

Comment: @nishantagrawal The last statement in any method (in Ruby) is automatically the returned value. You really only need to every use `return` to return early.